# Merging 2 Entries Array's

Tags: merge, craft2

I have these to arrays that I need to merge into one array, but can't figure it out.

Please advise

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('publications').search('nonMembers:0') %}

{% set entries = craft.entries.section('improveYourClub').search('membersExclusive:1') %}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just a few side notes:

1. neither the first `entries` variable nor the second `entries` variable is an array - both are objects of kind `craft\elements\db\EntryQuery` (or `craft\ElementCriteriaModel` if it's Craft 2).
2. `.search('nonMembers:0')` can be shortened to `nonMembers(0)` (or `"0"` or `"not 1"` depending on the type) and `search('membersExclusive:1')` to `membersExclusive(1)` it will increase your performance as well

So far about that.. You can merge arrays in Twig via [|merge](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/merge.html) filter

```twig
{% set values = [1, 2] %}

{% set values = values|merge(['apple', 'orange']) %}

{# values now contains [1, 2, 'apple', 'orange'] #}
```

---

**EDIT:**

To address your case specifically, you'll need something like this...

```
{% set entriesOne = craft.entries.section('publications').search('nonMembers:0').find() %}
{% set entriesTwo = craft.entries.section('improveYourClub').search('membersExclusive:1').find() %}

{% set allEntries = entriesOne|merge(entriesTwo) %}
```

Comment: In that case how do I merge the two objects

Comment: You can't merge objects. You can only merge the results of both queries

Comment: @CreateSean What Robin is saying is, add a `.find()` to the end of both queries. Then you'll have arrays of elements (instead of ElementCriteriaModels).

Comment: adding .find() returns a php notice with an Array to string conversion error. I had already tried that.

Comment: @CreateSean Just edited Robin's answer to use your specific code... give that a shot.

Comment: @lindsey I updated the post and continue to have array to string errors.

Comment: Could you maybe post your entire code? I guess the error is somewhere else